# Why does not my Hot Reload Flutter VSC work?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-hotreload

Sorry, I tried everithing (I think), but Hot Reload Doesn't work...
Everytime said when i press hotreload:

```
Reloaded 0 libraries in 197ms (compile: 15 ms, reload: 0 ms, reassemble: 60 ms).
E/gralloc4( 9473): Empty SMPTE 2094-40 data
```

I have the AutoSave, I have the "all" in hotReload Settings, I tried with -clean,pub get, run-..... I tried, but it doesn't work... please helpme.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true, colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blueGrey),
        home: const CounterFunctionScreen());
  }
}
```

and the code of CounterFunctionScreen is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CounterFunctionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CounterFunctionScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CounterFunctionScreen> createState() => _CounterFunctionScreenState();
}

class _CounterFunctionScreenState extends State<CounterFunctionScreen> {
  int clickCounter = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("nuevow"),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh_rounded), 
            onPressed: () {  },
            ),

        ),
        body: Center(
            child:
                Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Text('$clickCounter',
              style:
                  const TextStyle(fontSize: 100, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          Text('Click${clickCounter == 1 ? '' : 's'}',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50)),

        ])),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            clickCounter++;
            setState(() {}); //esto es para renderizar de nuevo el widget
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.plus_one),
        ));
  }
}
```

my debug console showme:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on M2101K7BL in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:52116/I1m4zh-07XQ=/ws
E/ion     ( 9473): ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
D/hw-ProcessState( 9473): Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
E/gralloc4( 9473): Empty SMPTE 2094-40 data
D/BLASTBufferQueue( 9473): [SurfaceView[com.example.hello_word_app/com.example.hello_word_app.MainActivity]#1](f:0,a:1) acquireNextBufferLocked size=1080x2270 mFrameNumber=1 applyTransaction=true mTimestamp=81623914588710(auto) mPendingTransactions.size=0 graphicBufferId=40686225195008 transform=0
D/.hello_word_app( 9473): MiuiProcessManagerServiceStub setSchedFifo
I/MiuiProcessManagerImpl( 9473): setSchedFifo pid:9473, mode:3
E/gralloc4( 9473): Empty SMPTE 2094-40 data
D/BLASTBufferQueue( 9473): [VRI[MainActivity]#0](f:0,a:1) acquireNextBufferLocked size=1080x2400 mFrameNumber=1 applyTransaction=true mTimestamp=81623947096787(auto) mPendingTransactions.size=0 graphicBufferId=40686225195009 transform=0
W/Parcel  ( 9473): Expecting binder but got null!
D/DecorView[]( 9473): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
I/HandWritingStubImpl( 9473): refreshLastKeyboardType: 1
2 I/HandWritingStubImpl( 9473): getCurrentKeyboardType: 1
E/gralloc4( 9473): Empty SMPTE 2094-40 data
W/MirrorManager( 9473): this model don't Support
```

Thanks,

help to giveme the answer for use the hotreload.

Comment: Maybe you can test on other devices or the web to exclude the possibility of the problem on the test device.